# Getting rid of extra test during initialization of loop/recursion

Tags: algorithm, recursion, clojure

I'm reluctant to ask this question.  My code below works, it's intelligible, and it seems reasonably efficient.  It's just that there's a trivial, nitpicky issue that's driving me crazy.  The function `maxes` below collects all elements of a sequence that are "maximum" according to some criterion.

```
;; Example of use of maxes
;; Collect all maps with the maximum value for `:a`:
(maxes :a [{:a 1 :b 2} {:a 4 :b 5} {:a 5 :b 5} {:b 3 :a 5}])
;;=> [{:b 5, :a 5} {:b 3, :a 5}]

(defn- maxes-helper
  "Helper function for maxes."
  [f s best-val collected]
  (if (empty? s)
    collected
    (let [new-elt (first s)
          new-val (f new-elt)]
      (cond (== new-val best-val) (recur f (rest s) best-val (conj collected new-elt))
            (>  new-val best-val) (recur f (rest s) new-val  [new-elt])
            :else                 (recur f (rest s) best-val collected)))))

(defn maxes
  "Returns a sequence of elements from s, each with the maximum value of (f element)."
  [f s]
  (if (empty? s)
    nil
    (let [new-elt (first s)
          new-val (f new-elt)]
      (maxes-helper f (rest s) new-val [new-elt]))))
```

What's really bugging me that I have to test for emptiness of the input collection `s` both in the top-level function and in the tail-recursive helper function.  I also want to add a custom exception when `(f new-elt)` is non-numeric, and so I need to test that twice, both for `new-val` and for first call to `(f new-elt)` that becomes the first `best`. So I've got a trivial amount of duplication of code, and I keep thinking that there must be a way to get rid of the duplication.  But I can't see how to do this (without testing that `best` is numeric on every iteration).  Am I missing something obvious (or non-obvious)?

(BTW I wrote another version using `reduce`, but it's about twice as slow, according to Criterium.)

Comment: If that's where it belongs, I'll be happy to move it there.  My question is pretty narrow.  It looks to me like the focus at Code Review is broader: "Here's my code; how can I improve it?"  I think that what I wrote is pretty good, but I'm open to suggestions for entirely different methods.

Comment: My previous comment responded to a comment on StackOverflow.  No longer makes sense--feel free to ignore it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need the helper function, the original `maxes`is pretty much equivalent to call `maxes-helper` with a sensible `MIN_VALUE` and empty sequence, so I refactored and joined both for you leveraging [multi-arity](http://clojure-doc.org/articles/language/functions.html#multi-arity-functions)

```
   (defn maxes
      "Returns a sequence of elements from s, each with the maximum value of (f element)."
      ([f s]
       (maxes f s Double/NEGATIVE_INFINITY '()))
      ([f s best-val collected]
      (if (empty? s)
        collected
        (let [new-elt (first s)
              new-val (f new-elt)]
          (cond (>  new-val best-val) (recur f (rest s) new-val  [new-elt])
                (== new-val best-val) (recur f (rest s) best-val (conj collected new-elt))
                :else                 (recur f (rest s) best-val collected))))))
```

Edited to replace `nil` by `Double/NEGATIVE_INFINITY` as suggested by @fmikes

Comment: `Double/NEGATIVE_INFINITY` is an interesting `MIN_VALUE`. (It lets you eliminate the `nil?` check.)

Comment: That's beautiful.  Thank you, James Sharp and @mfikes.